# Sensitivity of human eye to luminance

Tags: neuroscience, vision, color

I heard once that the human eye has a logarithmic scale for luminance, e.g. to "feel" that a surface is three times as luminous compared to another, the former emits a light 8 times more powerful than the latter. Definitions are indeed vague as my memory doesn't serve me well.

Is this based on anything scientific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Stevens & Galanter (1957)

> Although an extensive investigation of the subjective scale of
>   brightness is still in progress in this laboratory, enough has been
>   learned to show that, for patches of white light viewed in a dark
>   room, **subjective brightness is a power function of luminance**.
>   Moreover, **the exponent is of the order of one-third** which is in
>   reasonable agreement with results obtained by Hanes.

[image: Fig. 1A from Stevens & Galanter (1957)]

- Stevens, S. S., & Galanter, E. H. (1957). Ratio scales and category scales for a dozen perceptual continua. Journal of Experimental Psychology, 54(6), 377.

and the related study that is mentioned:

- Hanes, R. M. (1949). The construction of subjective brightness scales from fractionation data: a validation. Journal of experimental psychology, 39(5), 719.

Comment: actually if I'm not mistaken decibels are a logarithmic measure, so it's a power law over a logarithmic scale, right?

Comment: No. decibels are indeed logarithmic, but note that the x-axis is "linear" in decibels, and the y-axis is logarithmic. So the relation between subjective estimate and luminance is linear in a log-log plot, i.e., a power-law.

Answer (score 2):

This logarithmic increase in order to produce a just noticeable difference between stimuli of two different intensities is in fact a general property or the sensory system. It is known as [(Weber-) Fechner's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law):

> Weber's law states that the just-noticeable difference between two
>   stimuli is proportional to the magnitude of the stimuli. Gustav
>   Theodor Fechner (1801–1887), a scholar of Weber, later used Weber's
>   findings to construct a psychophysical scale in which he described the
>   relationship between the physical magnitude of a stimulus and its
>   (subjectively) perceived intensity. **Fechner's law (better referred to
>   as Fechner's scale) states that subjective sensation is proportional
>   to the logarithm of the stimulus intensity**.